# Visual studio 2022 with azurite integrated (v3.14.1) In creation of local blob container gives error message InvalidHeaderValue

Tags: azure, azurite

**This is the error that is thrown:**

```
Headers:
Server: Azurite-Blob/3.14.1
x-ms-error-code: InvalidHeaderValue
x-ms-request-id: a3aca2f1-c0af-4af5-a54c-d7e24c188ba0
Date: Mon, 21 Mar 2022 13:22:04 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: REDACTED
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <Error>
    <Code>InvalidHeaderValue</Code>
     <Message>The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
    RequestId:a3aca2f1-c0af-4af5-a54c-d7e24c188ba0
    Time:2022-03-21T13:22:04.189Z</Message>
    <HeaderName>x-ms-version</HeaderName>
    <HeaderValue>2021-04-10</HeaderValue>
    </Error>
```

If I look on Github : `https://github.com/Azure/Azurite` .And read the description from :

***API Version Compatible Strategy***

If an incoming request has a higher API version than Azurite, Azurite will return a InvalidHeaderValue error for x-ms-version (HTTP status code 400 - Bad Request).

What can be correct because in the api errormessage it claims that there is a headervalue : HeaderValue: 2021-04-10 (what is the newest api version 3.16.0 of Azurite see github).
And if you look to the error again in the Headers is the azurite(server) AZurite-blob/3.14.1 . The version that is delivered with VS2022. So, this means that the headervalue is from the latest azurite version, but the azurite server that is used is version 3.14.1

My question is how can I upgrade my local azurite version to 3.16.0 or downgrade some process that uses v3.16.0 to 3.14.1

I hope somebody can help me out here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using some SDK to create the blob container? Please share those details.

Comment: I use the nuget packages Azure.Storage.Blobs v12.11.0 and Azure.Storage.Common v12.10.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each version of the SDK as well as Azurite targets a specific REST API version. The reason you are getting this error is because installed version of Azurite targets an older REST API version than the SDK you are using.

Two possible solutions:

1. **Upgrade the Azurite version**: If you have installed Azurite through npm, simply execute the following command to upgrade to the latest version of Azurite.

```
npm update -g azurite
```

2. **Downgrade the SDK version**: You can downgrade the SDK version from 12.11.0 to 12.10.0. Please check the [changelog](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/CHANGELOG.md) before downgrading to ensure that your code is not using anything specific to the latest version. You will need to uninstall version 12.11.0 and then install 12.10.0.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The version of npm was already the latest version. So, I decided to use that version in stead of the integrated azurite version of VS2022.
Regards,
Marc

Comment: Microsoft really needs to fix this.  How is it to hard to keep their own updates in sync :/

Answer (score 6):

I updated my visual studio 2022 to version 17.2.5. It updated the azurite to version 3.17.1. And that got rid of this `InvalidHeaderValue` runtime error.

Also, it might help someone to know that I started to get this error after I updated my .NET project version to .NET 6 from .NET 5.